# How to clear notifications in the Google Cloud Platform console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, console

I use the web-based console of the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) to do debugging or testing tasks that might fail (the others are automated with the `gcloud` CLI). As a consequence, I have a growing list of **failed** tasks. Each one increments the counter of the alert badge on my notifications icon in the upper right. That is annoying. More importantly, I am never sure whether a recent issue came up ("was the counter 934 or 933 before?").

**My question:** how can I clear the notifications? I can't find a button in the pop-up, nor in the activity overview. A screenshot of the pop-up is linked [here](https://i.imgur.com/n37Tshk.png). In the upper right one can see the red *8* indicating that a total of 8 tasks failed in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a "CLEAR" button under Filters in the Activity tab (under Home -> ACTIVITY -> FILTER).

That seemed to work for me to remove the notification count from the bell icon in the top bar.  The notifications are still listed, but the count is gone.

Comment: The clear button just clears the filter for me, the notifications remain unchanged, and I still have this red count increasing because of past notifications. It's quite annoying, I always have the feeling that something is wrong

Answer (score 1):

In the activity log, you have the possibility to filter the events that are displayed by clicking on "view all activities" at the bottom of the notifications list.

This could be an alternative, as keeping past activity event log can be useful for debugging.

I have created a feature request on your behalf to consider the convenience of being able to delete past activity events with Google backend engineers. There is no estimated time of arrival for this feature to be applied, but it might be implemented in the future.
You can  do a follow up from this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/110026213).